# Disable interactivity of html object that's previewing a website

Tags: php, html, html-object

I'm loading in a preview of a website with the following code:

```
<object class="preview" type="text/html" data="<?php echo the_sub_field('prototype'); ?>"></object>
```

Is there a way to disable interactivity with the elements within that link? I want to load a preview of a link but I don't want users clicking around and interacting with the preview if that makes sense.

Comment: puting other div overlaping your object, is an idea ( like preload  do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). It would look something like this:

```
.preview {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

For browser support check out: [caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

You should also look at [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) if you want to show another website (it has several security features).

Comment: Saw this question and that's a really nice solution!